# Qt: Unable to parse certain svg item styles

Tags: c++, xml, qt, svg, xml-parsing

I am trying to display and modify some svg, I would like to be able to read or modify their color.

```
GraphicsColorSvgItem::GraphicsColorSvgItem(QString svgContent, QGraphicsItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsSvgItem(parent),
    _svgXML()
{
    _svgXML.setContent(svgContent);
    setSharedRenderer(new QSvgRenderer(_svgXML.toByteArray()));
}

void GraphicsColorSvgItem::setColor(QColor c)
{
    changeAttributes("fill", c.name().toUpper());
    changeAttributes("stroke", c.name().toUpper());
    changeAttributes("style", c.name().toUpper());   // this obviously needs to be treated separately just don't know how
    renderer()->load(_svgXML.toByteArray());
}

void GraphicsColorSvgItem::changeAttributes(QString attName, QString attValue)
{
    QDomElement rootElem = _svgXML.documentElement();
    QDomNode n = rootElem.firstChild();
    while(!n.isNull())
    {
        if(n.isElement())
        {
            QDomElement e = n.toElement();
            QSTRING_DEBUG(e.tagName());
            if(e.hasAttribute(attName))
            {
                e.setAttribute(attName, attValue);
            }
            if(n.hasChildNodes())
                recursiveChangeAttributes(n.firstChild(), attName, attValue);
        }
        n = n.nextSibling();
    }
}

void GraphicsColorSvgItem::recursiveChangeAttributes(QDomNode node, QString attName, QString attValue)
{
    QDomNode n = node;
    while(!n.isNull())
    {
        if(n.isElement())
        {
            QDomElement e = n.toElement();
            if(e.hasAttribute(attName))
            {
                e.setAttribute(attName, attValue);
            }
            if(n.hasChildNodes())
                recursiveChangeAttributes(n.firstChild(), attName, attValue);
        }
        n = n.nextSibling();
    }
}
```

The following svg is changed successfully to a color I pass

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

The following svg though has a "style" property - I don't know how to parse it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg height="250" width="500">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

The result comes out black - because the entire "style" is set to something not supported.

Edit: for now I am doing a string replace and it seems to work... But I am hoping for an xml method...

```
if(attName=="style")
{
    QString value = e.attribute(attName);
    int fill1 = value.indexOf(QString("fill:")) + 5;
    int fill2 = value.indexOf(QString(";"), fill1);
    if(fill2<=fill1)
       fill2 = value.indexOf(QString("\""), fill1);
    QString subString = value.mid(fill1, fill2 - fill1);
    value.replace(subString, attValue);    
    fill1 = value.indexOf(QString("stroke:")) + 7;
    fill2 = value.indexOf(QString(";"), fill1);
    if(fill2<=fill1)
       fill2 = value.indexOf(QString("\""), fill1);
    subString = value.mid(fill1, fill2 - fill1);
    value.replace(subString, attValue);
    e.setAttribute(attName, value);
}
else
{
    e.setAttribute(attName, attValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is found inside a style attribute is typically CSS style syntax.  So using a parser that supports CSS is probably your best bet.  Regular Expressions may be useful, but might not be the easiest to use...

With that said, I would switch to something like:

```
if(attName=="style")
{
    QString value = e.attribute(attName);

    QStringList styleList = value.split(";");
    QStringList newStyleList;
    foreach(QString style, styleList)
    {
        QStringList propertyVal = style.split(":");
        QString prop = propertyVal.first().trimmed();
        QString newVal = propertyVal.at(1).trimmed();
        if(prop == "stroke")
        {
            newVal = attValue;
        }
        else if(prop == "fill")
        {
            newVal = attValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // no changes
        }
        newStyleList.append(prop + ":" + newVal);
    }

    e.setAttribute(attName, newStyleList.join(";"));
}
```

Here is an example of a regular expression that could work.

```
/fill:(.*?)(?=;|$)/
```

Which translates to:

Find the word `fill`, followed by a colon, and then as few characters as possible until a semicolon is found or until the end of the string is found.

In the list of capture groups, the first group (after the zeroth), should contain the string for the value of the property value pair.

This expression would then need to be put in a `QRegularExpression` and used on the string.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details

Hope that helps.